# Equals command "Attrib -s -h /s /d" from cmd windows to terminal osx?

Tags: windows, macos, cmd, terminal, command

How to implement command "attrib -s -h /s /d" from cmd windows to terminal osx? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

OS X doesn't have a "system" flag (`-s`), but you can remove the hidden flag (`-h`) from a folder and its contents including subfolders (`/s /d`, if I understand `attrib` syntax correctly) with:

chflags -R nohidden /path/to/folder

Comment: Actually, there are "system" `chflags` on `OS X` (`sappnd`, `schg`), although they have a different purpose/meaning I suppose. Windows defines `-s` as "A file or directory that the operating system uses a part of, or uses exclusively." — hmmm... that could in essence be *any* file or directory.